# TypeError: expected string or buffer with Pandas wide_to_long function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use wide_to_long to reorganize a dataframe.

My current df looks like this just with tons more columns that would eventually be like math_b, reading_c, etc:

```
Course Code   StudentID   score-reading_a   letter-reading_a   score-math_a   letter-math_a
ABC123        123456      98                A                  96             A
ABC123        987654      77                C                  88             B
DEF456        102938      88                B                  99             A
```

I added an index column to the end with `df['index'] = df.index`

My goal was to get the df looking more like this:

```
Course Code   Student ID   subject   score   letter
ABC123        123456       reading_a 98      A
ABC123        123456       math_a    96      A
ABC123        987654       reading_a 77      C
ABC123        987654       math_a    88      B
DEF456        102938       reading_a 88      B
DEF456        102938       math_a    99      A
```

This is my statement:

`df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['score', 'letter'], i='index', j='subject', sep='-')`

And I'm getting this error:

```
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['score', 'letter'], i='index', j='subject', sep='-')        
  File "C:\Users\...\pandas\core\reshape\melt.py", line 446, in wide_to_long
    value_vars = [get_var_names(df, stub, sep, suffix) for stub in stubnames]
  File "C:\Users\...\pandas\core\reshape\melt.py", line 417, in get_var_names
    return [col for col in df.columns if pattern.match(col)]
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong with the statement. I did rename the columns earlier using a list like this because the original column names were really messy:

```
headers = ['Course Code', 'Student ID', 'score-reading_a', 'letter-reading_a',
           'score-math_a', 'letter-math_b']

df.columns = [headers]
```

Did reassigning the columns this way cause it to not be able to identify the column names? Or am I totally off and doing something completely wrong? I tried converting the column names to strings which threw an error about MultiIndex, but also my MultiIndex only had 1 level. I used a statement like this to try converting it a different way, but it just messed up the headers and left me with an empty dataframe once the wide_to_long function ran:

`df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns.values]`

The only other code outside of this that I didn't write down is my read_csv statement.

I did get the data looking the way I wanted with loops and concat, but I was hoping to use something a little more condensed.

Comment: You have not yet offered a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is likely to impact the quality of responses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) :

```
out = (df.set_index(["Course Code", "StudentID"])
           .pipe(lambda df_: df_.set_axis(df_.columns
                        .str.split("-", expand=True), axis=1))
           .stack().reset_index().rename({"level_2": "subject"}, axis=1)
      )​
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Course Code  StudentID    subject letter  score
0      ABC123     123456     math_a      A     96
1      ABC123     123456  reading_a      A     98
2      ABC123     987654     math_a      B     88
3      ABC123     987654  reading_a      C     77
4      DEF456     102938     math_a      A     99
5      DEF456     102938  reading_a      B     88
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the TypeError using `df.rename` function for the column names instead of using a list. That was my main question here and I'll troubleshoot the other issue separately.

Thanks all for your input - I appreciate it.